# What are filters in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What are the filters in asp.net mvc, can any one explain clearly. 
How to create a custom filters in asp.net mvc 4

```
[Authorize]
Public ActionResults Index()
{
    return View()
};
```

Comment: Did you google "ASP.NET action filters"? What don't you understand?

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am new to the Asp.net mvc.In which order the action filters will work.

Comment: You can check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Filters-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC, controllers define action methods that usually have a one-to-one relationship with possible user interactions, such as clicking a link or submitting a form. For example, when the user clicks a link, a request is routed to the designated controller, and the corresponding action method is called.
Sometimes you want to perform logic either before an action method is called or after an action method runs. To support this, ASP.NET MVC provides action filters. Action filters are custom attributes that provide a declarative means to add pre-action and post-action behavior to controller action methods.

Check [Filters-and-Attributes-in-ASPNET-MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/577776/Filters-and-Attributes-in-ASPNET-MVC)

Answer (score -1):

The filter attribute has the Order property which can be used to manage the orders. The order needs to be the order the business process to be followed. For example if HandleError attribute is given higher order than the Authorize attribute then even an unauthorized users will be getting application errors. It would be better saying "Please Login".